# How to Deploy PHP application on CloudFoundry?

Tags: php, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy my Plain PHP application on ColudFoundry ... But i cant get what exactly steps should i follow ? anybody please help me to deploy it on CloudFoundry.

Comment: let me see the steps you have taken to get there!

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to deploy the PHP app to CloudFoundry.com? If so, PHP is not enabled there. PHP support is in the opensource project at https://github.com/cloudfoundry and on some PaaS providers using Cloud Foundry, such as AppFog: http://appfog.com/

You can check if PHP is an available runtime by running `vmc runtimes`.

For general instructions on deploying a PHP app to a Cloud Foundry instance that supports it:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/oss-docs/tree/master/vcap/php_support

Answer (score 1):

CloudFoundry.com does not have support for all that is checked into CloudFoundry.org but there are other Cloud Foundry providers that provide more cutting edge services.

http://appfog.com/ provides PHP and Python support built-in, as well as languages like Java, Node, and Ruby.

AppFog was also the company who contributed PHP support to Cloud Foundry and has the benefit of running in US, EU, and Asia.